# How to remove Homebrew formula/keg that no longer exists?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to remove `extempore` but I get the following:

`$ brew uninstall extempore
Error: No available formula with the name "extempore-llvm"`

Trying to uninstall extempore-llvm

`$ brew uninstall extempore-llvm
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/extempore-llvm`

Adding `--force` does not do anything.

How do I remove this keg/formula completely? Brew can't uninstall/install/reinstall anything while this is an issue.

Comment: I am stuck on the same frustrating problem. Did you find a solution for this?thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/usr/local/Cellar/extempore-llvm` manually, then execute `brew cleanup`.

Comment: Thanks! I remove /usr/local/Cellar/extempore and ran brew prune and I'm able to use brew properly now