# Brew remove mysql error

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, homebrew

I want to completely remove MySQL from my mac (El Capitan).

I installed `homebrew` and tried to remove MySQL, but I get the error:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
```

Comment: Maybe this will a help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41161503/

Comment: Did you install MySQL using homebrew? Or by installer packages manually?

Answer (score 14):

Actually, by running

```
brew remove mysql
```

It is expecting a package called mysql and a corresponding folder in `/usr/local/Cellar`. But if you installed a specific version of mysql such as mysql@5.7, then that is what you would have to remove:

```
brew remove mysql
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
```

Try the version installed:

```
brew remove mysql@5.7
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.24... (319 files, 234.5MB)
```

Comment: I tried so many articles but only this line worked - brew remove mysql@5.7 .. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by manually going to /usr/local directory. There was one mysql folder, I deleted. Also, delete my.cnf file, should be present  It started working after that. If that too doesn't work, re-install homebrew, that will rectify symlink problem.